# Custom Events in Corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

How to write custom events in Corda?
For eg:- When i transfer a token from one account to another account, so that i will trigger an event to notify the account "Token is transferred" Or "Token is received".

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches:

1. Add the code that notifies the account inside of your issue or move tokens flow.
2. Create a `CordaService` that uses vault service's `trackBy()` function to subscribe to your state events (i.e. token created or token moved); and based on those events you'd notify the account.

   - Read about `trackBy()` [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-vault-query.html).
   - See an example of using `CordaService` with `trackBy()` [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/autopayroll-CordaService).

As for how to notify the account (send an email, place a message in some queue, call an API); that's up to you.